# ¿Es posible modificar el tamaño del logo en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy creando ventanas en **python** con **tkinter** y he modificado el logo por defecto.

```
window.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/icon.png'))
```

Me gustaría saber si puedo hacer mas grande el logo o la propia barra de la ventana de Windows.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes, porque para ello tendrías que modificar el tamaño de esa zona de la ventana que es un componente del sistema operativo que tkinter utiliza sin alterar.

Estas son todas las "libertades" que conozco relativas a los iconos en tkitner:

- Hacer un icono multisize en este [sitio](https://icoconvert.com/) de forma gratuita y usarlo en el ejecutable, de esta manera dependiendo del zoom en el navegador de archivos el icono del ejecutable se verá más o menos grande.
- También puedes convertir a base64 el icono para no depender del archivo icon.png de la ventana tkinter y tener el logo dentro del mismo código, más información [aquí](https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Tkinter_base64_Images).

Comment: Al convertirlo a base 32 o 64, si no me equivoco, voy a seguir necesitando el `png` en el código.

Comment: Es base64 y el png estaría en el código lo cual es útil si intentas crear un ejecutable de un solo archivo o para poner trabas para que no te roben el icono.

Answer (score 0):

Los iconos de ventana en Tkinter no se pueden cambiar de tamaño, utilizan la API del sistema solo que adaptado, dependiendo en el entorno operativo se adapta, el área
donde se muestra el icono es predeterminado de la ventana y no se puede alterar ni su tamaño ni su ubicación.

¿Pero para que sería necesario cambiar el tamaño del icono de la barra de la ventana?.
La única forma es que ubique el icono que quiere y ponerlo en la interfaz misma. El marco o la barra de las ventanas es predeterminado del propio sistema, Python es en gran parte multiplataforma, pero el intérprete real es específico para cada sistema operativo, de igual manera sucede con Tkinter.